# Lowest price in Magento category

Tags: php, magento

So I have created a sub.phtml file which creates category landing pages for me by retrieving the child categories of a category and displaying them on the page with the relevant title, image etc.

However I also would like to put the lowest price of a product in those categories ("From 19.99" for example)

Here is my current code:

```
<?php
$category = Mage::getSingleton('catalog/layer')->getCurrentCategory();
$categories = $category->getCollection()
        ->addAttributeToSelect(array('name', 'thumbnail'))
        ->addAttributeToFilter('is_active', 1)
        ->addIdFilter($category->getChildren())
        
?>

<?php
$lowest_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
    ->setOrder('price', 'asc')
    ->setPageSize(1) // just select one product, which will be the cheapest
    ->setCurPage(1)
    ->joinField(
        'category_id', 'catalog/category_product', 'category_id', 
        'product_id = entity_id', null, 'left'
    ) // add a join so you can filter by category id
    ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
    ->addAttributeToFilter('category_id', $category->getId())
    ->addAttributeToFilter('status', 1) // only select active products
    ->addAttributeToFilter(array(array('attribute'=>'visibility', 'eq'=>"4"))) // only products which are visible
    ->getFirstItem(); // only get the first item
?>
<div class="container">
    <?php foreach ($categories as $category): ?>
    <a class="catA" href="<?php echo $category->getUrl() ?>">
        <div class="catBox">
            <div class="catBoxImage"><img src="<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl('media') . 'catalog' . DS . 'category' . DS . $category->getThumbnail() ?>" alt="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($category->getName()) ?>"></div>
            <div class="catBoxText">
                <h2><?php echo $category->getName() ?></h2>
                <p class="catP">From: <span class="red"><?php echo Mage::helper('core')->currency(Mage::helper('tax')->getPrice($lowest_product, $lowest_product->getPrice()), true, false) ?></span></p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </a>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</div>
```

Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: Are you trying to get the lowest priced product within a category, or the lowest price of each product?

Comment: Sorry, the lowest priced product within a category

Answer (score 1):

To get the lowest priced product within a category you can do the following:

```
$lowest_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
    ->setOrder('price', 'asc')
    ->setPageSize(1) // just select one product, which will be the cheapest
    ->setCurPage(1)
    ->joinField(
        'category_id', 'catalog/category_product', 'category_id', 
        'product_id = entity_id', null, 'left'
    ) // add a join so you can filter by category id
    ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
    ->addStoreFilter(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId())
    ->addAttributeToFilter('category_id', $category->getId())
    ->addAttributeToFilter('status', 1) // only select active products
    ->addAttributeToFilter(array(array('attribute'=>'visibility', 'eq'=>"4"))) // only products which are visible
    ->getFirstItem(); // only get the first item
```

Now you can call:

```
<?php echo Mage::helper('core')->currency(Mage::helper('tax')->getPrice($lowest_product, $lowest_product->getPrice()), true, false) ?>
```

**UPDATED**

```
<?php
$category = Mage::getSingleton('catalog/layer')->getCurrentCategory();
$categories = $category->getCollection()
        ->addAttributeToSelect(array('name', 'thumbnail'))
        ->addAttributeToFilter('is_active', 1)
        ->addIdFilter($category->getChildren())

?>


<div class="container">
<?php foreach ($categories as $category): ?>
<?php
    $lowest_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
    ->setOrder('price', 'asc')
    ->setPageSize(1) // just select one product, which will be the cheapest
    ->setCurPage(1)
    ->joinField(
        'category_id', 'catalog/category_product', 'category_id', 
        'product_id = entity_id', null, 'left'
    ) // add a join so you can filter by category id
    ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
    ->addStoreFilter(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId())
    ->addAttributeToFilter('category_id', array('in' => $category->getId()))
    ->addAttributeToFilter('status', 1) // only select active products
    ->addAttributeToFilter(array(array('attribute'=>'visibility', 'eq'=>"4"))) // only products which are visible
    ->getFirstItem(); // only get the first item
?>

<a class="catA" href="<?php echo $category->getUrl() ?>">
    <div class="catBox">
        <div class="catBoxImage"><img src="<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl('media') . 'catalog' . DS . 'category' . DS . $category->getThumbnail() ?>" alt="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($category->getName()) ?>"></div>
        <div class="catBoxText">
            <h2><?php echo $category->getName() ?></h2>
            <p class="catP">From: <span class="red"><?php echo Mage::helper('core')->currency(Mage::helper('tax')->getPrice($lowest_product, $lowest_product->getPrice()), true, false) ?></span></p>
        </div>
    </div>
</a>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: Hmm, can't seem to get it to work, i'm pretty poor with PHP though so probably doing something wrong

Comment: It's because it's a collection so currently requires a foreach, I will amend my answer with a working fix.

Comment: Think it's almost there, only issue is it is displaying: 0.00 on all of the categories! - really appreciate the help by the way

Comment: I've tried it on a test installation and it works fine, could you use `<?php echo $lowest_product->getPrice() ?>` and let me know the output of that?

Comment: Hmm, the orginial one outputs "£0.00" on each one and that one outputs "0.00000s"

Comment: Do an echo for `$lowest_product->getName()` and then have a look at the product and make sure a price is actually set in the Admin

Comment: Ah, it's getting the same product across all categories (which doesn't have a price set) rather than the price in the specific category.

Comment: Afraid not as it is getting the cheapest product price across all categories rather than the from the category the block is representing

Comment: I have updated my question to show the code as it is now

Comment: You need to put my code within the foreach loop which you have, then it will work. As it needs to check for the lowest price for each of the categories. Having it outside only gets the current category.

Comment: Hi Karl, sorry it is still just showing the same price for all categories, i think it may be something to do with the echo but am not sure

Comment: It is strange as the product that it is getting the price from is not in any of the categories displayed

Comment: I've just tried my updated code on a test installation and it's worked perfectly, so it must be something to do with your products. So unfortunately, I cannot help any further at this point.

Comment: Could it be something to do our magento being a multi-store installation do you think?

Comment: Yes potentially.. I've updated my answer to take this in to account, please see the line `->addStoreFilter(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId())`

Comment: Still no change, really don't understand what is going on with it